# Trigger not working properly on batch update

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, triggers, sql-server-2000

I have a trigger that check data before insert to another table

```
  IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                 FROM   inserted,
                        Clients
                 WHERE  Inserted.Account = Clients.Account)
  BEGIN
      INSERT INTO Clients(GUID, Account, ....)
      SELECT GUID, Account
      FROM   inserted
  END
```

it's working fine if one row updated
but if use batch update its not working.

for example `Update Table1 set Number = Number where account <> ''`
If the second table (Clients) is not empty, nothing added
if it's empty its work well

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rather than doing a check then insert, why not write it as a single `INSERT` statement:

```
Insert into Clients (GUID , Account .....)
Select i.GUID , i.Account 
from
   inserted i
      left join
   Clients c
      on
          i.Account = c.Account
where
    c.Account is null
```

The `NULL` check in the `WHERE` clause can be for any column in `Clients` which isn't nullable.

---

Even if you keep the `EXISTS` check in, you still need something like the above, because the `EXISTS` check is asserting something about *all* of the rows in `inserted` - when it may consist of some rows for which the assertion is true, and some rows for which it is false.